# Installing a gem has no effect (aka how to use check_puppet.rb)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, puppet

I'm sure this question is an easy one for Ruby users. However for me this is a issue I can't figure out by myself.

My goal is to use a script included in the Puppet archive (ext/nagios/check_puppet.rb) on a Ubuntu-10.4 system.

I try to launch the script:

```
$ sudo ./check_puppet.rb
./check_puppet.rb:4:in `require': no such file to load -- sys/proctable (LoadError)
        from ./check_puppet.rb:4
```

Ok so there's something missing. I fount out I need some library called sys-proctable available at http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/sys-proctable/

```
wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/65609/sys-proctable-0.9.0-x86-linux.gem
[...]
sudo apt-get install rubygems
[...]
$ sudo gem install sys-proctable-0.9.0-x86-linux.gem
Successfully installed sys-proctable-0.9.0-x86-linux
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sys-proctable-0.9.0-x86-linux...
Installing RDoc documentation for sys-proctable-0.9.0-x86-linux...
```

Everything looks pretty good so far! Time to launch the script again

```
$ sudo ./check_puppet.rb
./check_puppet.rb:4:in `require': no such file to load -- sys/proctable (LoadError)
        from ./check_puppet.rb:4
```

the `gem list`output tells me this:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

sys-proctable (0.9.0)
```

- Where has this gem been installed?
- Why can't the script load the sys-proctable lib?
- What the *%&$@* am I doing wrong?
- Where's the official doc of `gem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gem is installed - but in Ruby 1.8 you need to have the line:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

To use rubygems. This changes the 'require' function so it will pull in rubygems when you ask it to.

So in the script:

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/ext/nagios/check_puppet.rb

Just add the require near the top and try again.

For instructions on other ways to use rubygems, consult the Rubygems documentation:

http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page70

Comment: Thanks for the easy answer. However I don't understand why the script does not work out of the box after installing the gem (and if possible, what to do if I want to avoid editing the script)

Comment: I've added a link to the docs that talk about this, but more or less - this should be raised as a bug in Puppet so it Just Works (tm). Or - you can use Ruby 1.9.x and it should just work.

Comment: You are awesome. Adding the `-rubygems` switch does the trick when using Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i am getting on centos 6.4

```
 sudo ./check_puppet.rb 
./check_puppet.rb:75:in `-': no implicit conversion to float from nil (TypeError)
    from ./check_puppet.rb:75:in `check_state'
    from ./check_puppet.rb:122
```

i added require 'rubygems'

and installed sys-proctable